# Why do I need that $F$ a relation to show $(F^{-1})^{-1} = F$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am doing some self-study from Enderton's *Elements of Set Theory* and he leaves Theorem 3E below to the reader to prove:

> **Theorem 3E.** (1) For a set $F$, dom $F^{-1} =$ ran $F$ and ran $F^{-1} =$ dom $F$. (2) For a relation $F$, $(F^{-1})^{-1} = F$.

The definition of the inverse of a set was given earlier as below:

> **Definition (inverse of a set).** The inverse of a set $F$ is the set $F^{-1} := \{\langle u,v \rangle \mid  \langle v,u \rangle \in F\}$ [this can be rigorously defined from the axioms of ZFC and $F$ being a set but it should be clear].

As is clear from the statement of the theorem, in the first part we demand only that $F$ is some set whereas in the second we demand that $F$ be a relation (a set which is constituted only of ordered pairs). My question is *why is this assumption about $F$ being a relation necessary*? I have supplied proofs of both statements below and cannot see where in the second one I've used that $F$ be a relation in particular:

(1) We have
$$x \in \textrm{dom} \,F^{-1} \iff \exists y(\langle x,y\rangle \in F^{-1}) \iff \exists y(\langle y,x\rangle \in F) \iff x \in \textrm{ran} \, F$$
which is sufficient by the Axiom of Extensionality. The other part of (1) goes through similarly.

(2) $$x \in (F^{-1})^{-1} \iff \exists a \exists b\left[(x = \langle a,b\rangle) \land (\langle b,a\rangle \in F^{-1}) \right] \iff \exists a \exists b\left[(x = \langle a,b\rangle) \land (\langle a, b\rangle \in F) \right] \iff x \in F$$
which, again, suffices by extensionality.

In this proof of (2) I cannot see where I've used that $F$ is a relation rather than a set. Can anyone set me straight? I am almost certain I am missing something because Enderton is *very* precise with his language (he goes on and on about defining things for the most general sets where possible) and would not have said this without good reason.

Comment: The last $\iff$ in your proof of (2) appears to be exactly the statement that $F$ is a relation. Otherwise, it may have elements that are not ordered pairs.

Comment: Oy, I think I see now (I will leave this question up for posterity I guess). Examining the *definition* of inverse it appears that it's always a relation no matter if $F$ is or not. That is, $F$ may be a general set but its inverse consists only of the "flipped" ordered pairs from ordered pairs which might (or might not) be in $F$. From there it follows that a necessary (but not sufficient) condition for some inverse to be equal to some set is that that latter set be in particular a relation. Thank you for pointing this out, @AndrewDudzik. (I'd be happy to accept an answer to that effect too.)

Comment: There's a mistake in (1). The third term should be $\exists y(\langle y,x\rangle \in F)$

Comment: Good catch, thank you! @jjagmath

Comment: Agreed Mauro, I was missing that while $F$ may be a general set, $F^{-1}$ is always a relation (consisting always of ordered pairs), potentially even the empty relation. Thank you! Happy to accept any answer to that effect too. @MauroALLEGRANZA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see (page 44) the *inverse* of $F$ is defined in general for a set $F$ whatever: but what $F^{−1}$ is when $F$ is not a relation? i.e. it is not a set of ordered pairs?

Recall that (page 40) $xFy$ is a shorthand for $\langle x,y \rangle \in F$; if not, $F^{−1}=\text {dom}F=\text{ran}F=\emptyset$.

Thus, the "trick" is that if $F$ is a not-empty set that is **not** a relation, then $F^{-1}=\emptyset$ and thus $(F^{−1})^{−1} \ne F$.

Comment: Absolutely, thank you Mauro! And I'll just add for myself (and for others who may come across this) that in the intermediate case wherein $F$ contains some ordered pairs and some elements which are not ordered pairs, the page 44 definition of $F^{-1}$ is such that it will not be empty -- it will consist precisely of the "flipped" ordered pairs for those elements of $F$ which are ordered pairs!

Comment: @EE18 - correct! You are welcome!